# Postfix: postmap error with pcre

Tags: linux, postfix, pcre

I am using `postfix-pcre` on debian linux.

When I run  `postmap /etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks.pcre` and `postmap pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks.pcre`, I get the following error:

```
postmap: warning: smtp_header_checks.pcre, line 1: record is in "key: value" 
format; is this an alias file?
```

What is wrong?  I have this in `/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks.pcre`:

```
# Remove sender's IP address information
/^Received: .*/ IGNORE
/^X-Originating-IP:/ IGNORE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to run `postmap` on postfix's pcre files.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** run postmap on PCRE, CIDR, REGEX, or TEXTMAP files.

Comment: Correction: you *can* run `postmap` on a pcre file; it even creates a `.db` after doing so.  However running `postmap` on a pcre file results in the errors shown in the question.

Comment: Since the context is "a working postfix installation", no, you cannot.

Comment: Help me understand what goes wrong if I did, because postfix was still working fine when I did it

Answer (score -1):

The space between the colon and period in line one causes the postmap warning message.